# Crossjoin between two dataframes that is dependent on a common column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A crossJoin can be done as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subgroup':['A','B','C','D']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(3), freq='D')})
sdf1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1)
sdf2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)

sdf1.crossJoin(sdf2).toPandas()
```

In this example there are two dataframes each containing 4 rows, in the end, I get 16 rows.

However, for my problem, I would like to do a cross join per user, and the user is another column in the two dataframes, e.g.:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'subgroup':['A','B','C','D','A','B','D','E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'dates':np.hstack([np.array(pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(3), freq='D')),np.array(pd.date_range(date_today+timedelta(1), date_today + timedelta(4), freq='D'))])})
```

The result of applying the per-user crossJoin should be a dataframe with 32 rows. Is this possible in pyspark and how can this be done?

Comment: Filter each dataframe into two, one for each user, crossjoin corresponding sub-dataframes (to get 2 dataframes each with 16 rows) then union the two crossjoined dataframes

Comment: @sramalingam24 , I should have mentioned that this should generalize to n users (i.e. more than 2)

Comment: Then you will have to write a function that does this over the range of user IDs preferably in map (filter&join) - reduce ( union) fashion

Comment: Doing this over a range of user ids would indeed be a solution if this could be done in a map reduce fashion. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I would greatly help if you could reduce your problem to a minimal instance and provide sample data and sample output so that we can know exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are the user IDs just integers going from 1 to n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cross join is a join that generates a multiplication of lines because the joining key does not identify rows uniquely (in our case the joining key  is trivial or there is no joining key at all)

Let's start with sample data frames:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import pyspark.sql.types as pst
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[user, value] for user, value in zip(5 * list(range(2)), np.random.randint(0, 100, 10).tolist())], 
    schema=pst.StructType([pst.StructField(c, pst.IntegerType()) for c in ['user', 'value1']]))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[user, value] for user, value in zip(5 * list(range(2)), np.random.randint(0, 100, 10).tolist())], 
    schema=pst.StructType([pst.StructField(c, pst.IntegerType()) for c in ['user', 'value2']]))

        +----+------+
        |user|value1|
        +----+------+
        |   0|    76|
        |   1|    59|
        |   0|    14|
        |   1|    71|
        |   0|    66|
        |   1|    61|
        |   0|     2|
        |   1|    22|
        |   0|    16|
        |   1|    83|
        +----+------+

        +----+------+
        |user|value2|
        +----+------+
        |   0|    65|
        |   1|    81|
        |   0|    60|
        |   1|    69|
        |   0|    21|
        |   1|    61|
        |   0|    98|
        |   1|    76|
        |   0|    40|
        |   1|    21|
        +----+------+
```

Let's try joining the data frames on a constant column to see the equivalence between a cross join and regular join on a constant (trivial) column:

```py
df = df1.withColumn('key', psf.lit(1)) \
    .join(df2.withColumn('key', psf.lit(1)), on=['key'])
```

We get an error from spark > 2, because it realises we're trying to do a cross join (cartesian product)

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1865.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
>   LogicalRDD [user#1538, value1#1539], false
>   and
>   LogicalRDD [user#1542, value2#1543], false
>   Join condition is missing or trivial.
>   Either: use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these
>   relations, or: enable implicit cartesian products by setting the configuration
>   variable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;

If your joining key (`user` here) is not a column that uniquely identifies rows, you'll get a multiplication of lines as well but within each `user` group:

```py
df = df1.join(df2, on='user')
print("Number of rows : \tdf1: {} \tdf2: {} \tdf: {}".format(df1.count(), df2.count(), df.count()))

        Number of rows :    df1: 10     df2: 10     df: 50

        +----+------+------+
        |user|value1|value2|
        +----+------+------+
        |   1|    59|    81|
        |   1|    59|    69|
        |   1|    59|    61|
        |   1|    59|    76|
        |   1|    59|    21|
        |   1|    71|    81|
        |   1|    71|    69|
        |   1|    71|    61|
        |   1|    71|    76|
        |   1|    71|    21|
        |   1|    61|    81|
        |   1|    61|    69|
        |   1|    61|    61|
        |   1|    61|    76|
        |   1|    61|    21|
        |   1|    22|    81|
        |   1|    22|    69|
        |   1|    22|    61|
        |   1|    22|    76|
        |   1|    22|    21|
        +----+------+------+
```

5 * 5 rows for user `0` + 5 * 5 rows for user `1`, hence 50

**Note:** Using a `self join` followed by a `filter` usually means you should be using ***window functions*** instead.